# Class activation heat map. ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 15 layers into a model with 16 layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to generate Class activation heat map on my dataset using VGG16. I had tried to execute this many times by using different methods but couldn't find a proper solution to this.

**Libraries are:**

```
# load requirements from the Keras library
# import numpy and keras preprocessing libraries
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

print('Tensorflow version',tf.__version__)
import numpy as np
import os
import imutils
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
```

**Base model on Vgg16 is:**

```
base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False, input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))
```

**Top Model is:**

```
model_top = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D()(base_model.output)
model_top = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(model_top)
model_top = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,activation='relu')(model_top)
model_top = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(model_top) 
model_top = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(model_top)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=model_top)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**Generators are:**

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,target_size=(img_height, img_width),batch_size=batch_size,class_mode='binary')
validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_data_dir,target_size=(img_height, img_width),batch_size=batch_size,class_mode='binary')
```

**Saving the base model and model on which I trained my dataset is:**

```
model.save("/content/vgg16model.h5")
base_model.save("/content/vgg16_basemodel.h5")
```

**But when I try to load trained weights error occurred**

```
K.clear_session()
model = VGG16(weights='/content/vgg16model.h5')
```

**Error:**
**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-21-cbb430a539c6> in <module>()
          3 K.clear_session()
          4 
    ----> 5 model = VGG16(weights='/content/vgg16model.h5')
    
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py in load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, layers)
        684                      'containing ' + str(len(layer_names)) +
        685                      ' layers into a model with ' + str(len(filtered_layers)) +
    --> 686                      ' layers.')
        687 
        688   # We batch weight value assignments in a single backend call
    
    ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 15 layers into a model with 16 layers.
```

I don't understand why it is happening every time even I tried it to other CNN architectures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you saved model in the file, I would recommend using of:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("/content/vgg16model.h5")
```

Comment: Yuri Krenin Thanks it is working!  But I couldn't understand the reason why the statement of model assignment (saving of model) in my code, not worked?

Comment: First of all, I never load model your way, but my guess is that you create model without top (include_top = False) than you saved it and, after that, you are trying to load model without specifying include_top = False, Therefore, VGG16 expects 16 layers and you have only 15. Just a guess.